# Is it possible to create and remove divs?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have to make a web dashboard for my school project. Problem is that I need to give the user the ability to create and add the squares which you see in this picture [image: Dashboard]

I don't know how to do this especially since I don't know javascript and they want us to use as little javascript as possible. Is it even possible to do it without javascript?

Comment: could you include some source so we can be more specific?

Comment: Yes, you can submit a value to the server which will store the values in a database. If it is only for one user, you can use localStorage and javascript. DO however post CODE instead of pictures. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]

Comment: The fact that you don't know Javascript would look to me as an argument *in favor* of using Javascript : now you have a specific, concrete, not-too-large objective, that would be great to start experimenting and learn a new language (especially a language like Javascript, which is ubiquitous in the web). Anyway, just some thoughts, not an actual answer to your question,

Comment: The answer for the title and body is "yes", but I assume the next question will then be "how?" which will become too broad for this site.

Comment: are you using any clientside toolkit at the moment? for example, jquery or any of the other *myriad* of client-side DOM manipulation tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JavaScript. You can create a `div` or any other tag with JavaScript like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div"); // or any tag
```

Then set the `style` properties of that div:

```
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
```

Check out [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) for other properties you can set/get. They also have a sandbox, somewhere you can play with the code to learn how things work.

Then you can set the contents of the div. Here you can add more HTML content to your div.

```
div.innerHTML = '<a href = "www.google.com">Google</a>';
```

Finally add the element (div in this case) to whatever element you prefer. Here I am adding it to an element that has `id = "main-container"`:

```
document.getElementById("main-container").appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery append

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("body").append("<div>Appended div</div>");
});
```

Or use appendChild() fucntion if you prefer pure JavaScript

```
var node = document.createElement("div");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(node);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm going to try and see if I can make it work with this information.